# I am trying to fix a computer and they have completly removed their App Data File?

Tags: windows-vista

They cannot update the computer files without it and also can’t read some of their emails as it comes up your app data folder is missing. I have looked all over for it and have also set a system recover for 2 weeks ago and they still haven’t shown up.

What else can I do? If all else fails can I take app data from another computer? Will it work the same?

Answer (score 1):

The AppData folder will be different for each user of each computer. You can't copy it because it hold specific information to the software installed on that particular PC by that user. Your kinda between a rock and a hard place with this one. It's going to require reinstalling all the applications.

Comment: Applications arent the problem! Its the email which came on the computer and Windows Update that dont work as far as I know.

Comment: You mean your Outlook doesnt work? Thats because the .pst file is stored in the appdata folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't gone too far, how about trying some undelete software? e.g. http://ntfsundelete.com/ (first search result I found!)

Obviously, the effectiveness of this will depend on how much the machine has been used before trying to retrieve the data, but you may get some!